# Add strings from the Post Flag History page into transifex (or use existed keys)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, international-sites, transifex

> [image]

I found strings like this in transifex, but looks like they aren't used on this page, and hardcoded.

Could you add this strings into transifex or use existed strings?