# Summarized list of diamond moderator tools pages with strings which need to be added into Transifex

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

In this post I want to summarize links to all posts related to localization of mod tools pages.

1. Moderator private messages: [The absence of some strings in Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311613/260198).
2. Post flag history page: [Add strings from the Post Flag History page into transifex (or use existed keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329166/260198).
3. User history page: [Use existed strings or add new into transifex for filters titles on the user history page in mod tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329200/260198).
4. Review queue stat page: [Add strings from the Review Queue stat page into transifex to make it possible to translate for Stackexchange localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329258/260198).
5. Mod history page: [Add string "Absence recorded at" from the mod history page into transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329273/260198).
6. Bans history page: [Add strings from the bans history page into transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329552/260198).
7. Mod dashboard: [Add string “Added Comment” from the mod dashboard into transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330822/260198).
8. Help page: [Add strings from help page into transifex (or use existing keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330839/260198).
9. Off-topic close reasons manage page: [Add strings from the off-topic close reasons manage page into transifex (or use existing keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330867/260198).
10. Mod analytics page: [Add string "error completing request; try again later" from analytics page into transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330878/260198).
11. Cross-referenced IP page: [Add strings from cross-referenced IP address page into Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330900/260198).
12. Recent Redactions page: [Add strings from Recent Redactions page into Transifex (or use existing keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330953/260198).
13. Community messages in mod dashboard: [Localize flag reason raised by Community user in mod dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330969/260198).
14. Post timeline page: [Add strings from the post timeline page into Transifex (or use existing keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330983/260198).
15. Community events page: [Add string "No Upcoming" from the community events page into Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331049/260198).
16. User comments page: [Add strings from the user comments pages into Transifex (or use existing keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331105/260198).
17. Cross-referenced IP Addresses page: [Add strings from the Cross-referenced IP Addresses page in case when there is no user with given id into Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331145/260198).
18. Deleted user page: [Add strings for the actions with an account on the deleted user page into Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331147/260198).
19. Users page: [Add strings from the admin/users page into Transifex (or use existed keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331182/260198).
20. Deleted user posts page: [Add strings for post types from the deleted user posts page into Transifex (or use existed keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331264/260198)
21. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) <s>Mod menu on question: [Add string "actions" from the mod menu on a question into Transifex (or use an existing key)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331620/260198).</s>
22. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) <s>Posts merge result page: [Add string “Moderator action succeeded” from the posts merge result page into Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331795/260198).</s>
23. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) <s>Moderator revision redaction approval page: [Add strings from moderator revision redaction approval block into Transifex (or use existing keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332282/260198).</s>
24. Post review history page: [Add strings from the Post Review History page into transifex (or use existed keys)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337105/260198).

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to prevent appearance of untranslatable strings in SE code base?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327742/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-appearance-of-untranslatable-strings-in-se-code-base)

Comment: What is this [Transifex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transifex) thing in this context? What is the why? E.g., does Stack Exchange have an account there? The tag wiki only says *"used by Stack Exchange"*. What does that mean? Perhaps explain it in the tag wiki?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q "Localization platform used by Stack Exchange for the localized sites, e.g. ru.SO and others". I don't what also should I add to this =/