# Add strings from cross-referenced IP address page into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/xref-user-ips/{uderId}

> [image]

Strings:

1. User.
2. Count.
3. From.
4. To.
5. Submit Query.

Please, for `Count` and `From` use separate keys (don't use existing keys).

Comment: Do you want SocketException included too? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @mdewey I guess, it isn't translatable (:

Comment: To have SocketException translated they might have to install te Russian languagepack for .Net ... that might give issues elsewhere ... as in: all expections and messages built-in for .Net will then be in Russian, everywhere.

Comment: @rene perfect :D