# Add strings from Recent Redactions page into Transifex (or use existing keys)

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/redactions

> [image]

Strings:

1. Last X Redactions
2. Post
3. Redactor
4. Date
5. Comment
6. Links
7. Revisions
8. List
9. Flag
10. Recent Redactions (in title)

Could you add these strings into transifex or use existing strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have been through this page and we now support translations for:

- The `<title>`
- The heading of "Last X Redactions"
- All table headings
- Links (Revisions List, Revisions, Flag)