# Localize flag reason raised by Community user in mod dashboard

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, international-sites

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/dashboard

> [image]

Currently text of reasons in English, e.g `Low answer quality score`. Could you localize those messages?

P.S. [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) is Russian brother of [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).