# Add strings from the post timeline page into Transifex (or use existing keys)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/953693/timeline#flag_339823

> [image: Post timeline]

Strings:

1. `Helpful` and, probably strings like `Declined`, etc (there are strings `3c5db2447415c261cf024be85458ce35` and others in transifex, but they aren't used here).
2. `ModRevisionRedactionApproval`, `PostOther` and other systemic strings.