# Unable to translate "No Upcoming" from the community events page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, events

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/community-events?tab=upcoming

> [image]

Could you please make string "No Upcoming" translatable?

Comment: It looks like the relevant line of code for this just displays the word "No" and then the (untranslated) title of the current tab (either "Upcoming" or "Past"), when there are no events to display. I suspect it wouldn't really be useful to make the word "No" separately translatable on its own, so this might require a bit more tweaking by the devs to make the combined phrase translatable as a single unit (i.e. as "No Upcoming Events" and "No Past Events").

Comment: @V2Blast sure. Wrong implementation in the beginning requires more effort further.