# Unable to translate "to" on new upcoming event page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, events

There's no source string to translate "to" word on upcoming event page in moderator tools:

> [image]

Related post for "No Upcoming" translation: [Unable to translate "No Upcoming" from the community events page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331049/339911)