# Add strings from the user comments pages into Transifex (or use existing keys)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/users/:userId/post-comments

1. `edit`.
2. `delete`

> [image]

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/users/:userId/post-comments?state=flagged

Strings for flag reasons:

1. `No Longer Needed by`.
2. `Not Constructive Or Off Topic by`.
3. etc