# Add strings from the Cross-referenced IP Addresses page in case when there is no user with given id into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/xref-user-ips/0

> [image]

Strings:

1. `No User Found`.
2. `No user found with Id =`.

Could you add those strings into Transifex, so we will be able to translate it?