# Add strings for the actions with an account on the deleted user page into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/:id

> [image: Actions with an account]

Could you add those strings into Transifex, so we will be able to translate them?

Comment: What exactly does „A mod has given feedback on this user“ mean?

Comment: @MEEwasthemissingbracket moderator can leave comment on user profile, which could be seen by other moderators.

Comment: Ah the user annotations. I was confused by the term feedback. :P