# Add strings from the admin/users page into Transifex (or use existed keys)

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/users

> [image]

Strings: `Users with Flagged Posts`.

Also, there is the string `all time` in Transifex with key `f270cf82d6f4111caff626149a9b9272`, but it looks like it isn't used here. The same for `last 30 days` (key `0295639119cdb22010b837e2cf76bf82`).

Could you add these strings into Transifex or use existed strings?