# Add strings for post types from the deleted user posts page into Transifex (or use existed keys)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts-by-deleted-user/:deletedUserId

> [image]

Strings:

1. `Answer`.
2. `Question`.
3. `TagWikiExcerpt`.
4. etc

Could you add these strings into Transifex or use existed strings?