# Add string "actions" from the mod menu on a question into Transifex (or use an existing key)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

Press "mod" to open the mod menu on a question.

> [image]

"actions" is not translated. There is the string "actions" (key `ebb67a4271abe715344471b0f16321f6`) in Transifex, but it looks like it isn't used.

Could you add this string into Transifex or use the existing string?

Comment: The UI for this has changed, and all strings on the new mod menu are in transifex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will *soon* be rendered moot by this change: [New mod-menu design rolling out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332324/new-mod-menu-design-rolling-out)