# Add string “Moderator action succeeded” from the posts merge result page into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/:postId/merge

> [image: The posts merge result page]

Could you add this string into Transifex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings should appear in Transifex soon.

```
3b451b62eb10ad59fcc42cd4669fed10    Moderator action succeeded
dc1c846bae2246b55309c3c751c96486    Moderator action failed
```