# Add strings from moderator revision redaction approval block into Transifex (or use existing keys)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/dashboard

> [image: Moderator revision redaction approval block]

Strings:

1. Question.
2. Rev.
3. Redactor.
4. Comment.
5. Diff.
6. Actions.
7. Approve.
8. Reject.

I've found some of this strings in Transifex, but looks like they aren't used. Could you add those strings into Transifex or use existing strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.