# Add strings from the Post Review History page into transifex (or use existed keys)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex, international-sites

> [image]

I found strings like this in transifex (for example there is a string "Post Review History" with key `2c6a0e5cb0ad95b1b014b3cfb98e105a`), but looks like they aren't used on this page, and hardcoded.

Could you add this strings into transifex or use existed strings?